# Configuring Solaris 10 SPARC for internet ready connection

Tags: networking, solaris, router, modem, sparc

I have a Oracle SPARC server with Solaris SPARC 10 OS installed

I have a domestic router/modem box from my ISP in my house. I have a wifi extender in my room which has a RJ45 female socket for ethernet connection. The Wifi extender is configured properly to act as a bridge for machines to connect with my router/modem.

I have setup my NIC card in Solaris 10 with the following commands

```
dladm show-link
ifconfig e1000g0 plumb up
ifconfig 192.168.0.22 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast + up
```

I have put the IP address of 192.168.0.22 into the /etc/defaultrouter file and again the same IP address in /etc/hostname.e1000g0 file

Next I typed in 'init 6' to reboot Solaris 10. 
Once Solaris 10 is up again I can successfully ping the address of 192.168.0.22. But my router obviously needs a password as it is a WPA protected domestic router. This means programs like WGET which needs an URL address to download data doesnt work ATM. Does anyone know what to do to complete the tasks of making my server internet ready. Thanks in advance for any help given to me

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You do not put your Solaris IP address in `/etc/defaultrouter`
You put the address of the router, which must be in the local network of your Solaris box.  It may end with .1 or .250--you need to find out (try `ping`). For example, in your case it may be `192.168.0.1`.  After that you also need to configure `/etc/resolv.conf` with your DNS servers.